# How can I set a build variable in Azure DevOps with Bash?

Tags: bash, azure-devops

I'm using the below to pull the version from my package.json file and set it to one of my build variables, `Version`.

```
# successfully retrieves and prints the version to console
ver=$(node -e "console.log(require('./package.json').version)")
echo "Version: $ver"

# does jack squat
# even trying to hard-code something in place of $ver doesn't set the variable
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Version]$ver"
echo "Version: $(Version)"
```

I've tried using `ver` and `$(ver)` instead of `$ver`, none work as the console prints a blank for `$(Version)` in all cases (it's empty to begin with). If I hard-code `Version`, it prints fine, so it's not the printing or the retrieving, it's the setting that's the issue. I've based my script on MS' example,

`echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=sauce]crushed tomatoes"`

Our build server is in a Windows environment.

Comment: If you storing the output of `$(..)` in the variable `ver`, then `echo "$ver"` should produce the result you need

Comment: @Inian So, `echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Version]$ver"` looks correct to you, then? Cuz it does me.

Comment: Take a look at this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=vsts&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch) on referencing variables from different context.  I think you need to reference as $VERSION for a bash script.

Comment: @Inian it doesn't work. When I try to print the build variable in the last line, it's blank, not 1.0.0 like it is in the `ver` variable.

Comment: I'll give that a shot, @Matt. Just waiting on a build agent...

Comment: @Yatrix: Maybe the `node` commands writes to standard error stream. Could you append `2>&1` as `node -e "console.log(require('./package.json').version)" 2>&1`

Comment: @Inian The node looks to be fine. I'm successfully retrieving the version and setting it to the `ver` variable. I just can't set the build variable (`Version`) to the `ver` variable.

Comment: @Matt that didn't work.

Answer (score 10):

coming at this a while after posting, but thought I'd share just in case others stumble upon this.

From the documentation, the pipeline variable doesn't get expanded until after the task is over. [Microsoft has enhanced their documentation to illustrate it better](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch)

```
steps:

# Create a variable
- script: |
    echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=sauce]crushed tomatoes'

# Use the variable
# "$(sauce)" is replaced by the contents of the `sauce` variable by Azure Pipelines
# before handing the body of the script to the shell.
- script: |
    echo my pipeline variable is $(sauce)
```

I suspect that is why even when hard coding a value, you weren't seeing anything still.

Comment: is this for bash?

Comment: @MaxBarrass this is for a yaml configuration file, you'll have to use the echo statements. But what Andy is getting at is that it needs to be used in the subsequent task. This makes sense because your code all seems to be in the same file

Comment: @BigMoney it seem that OP is doing a bash script as $() is sub-bash eval. Also in bash ""(double quotes) means that expression will be evaluated more consistently than ''(single quotes). Ah and yes Microsoft uses $() for variable eval which is not how it works in actual bash (not sure why they call it that) here are examples https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch

Answer (score 6):

After this line
`echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Version]$ver"`
the value is stored in an environment variable VERSION.

You can access it in a **next** script-step, using:

```
- bash: |
    echo "my environment variable is $VERSION"
- pwsh: |
    Write-Host "my environment variable is $env:VERSION"
- script: |
    echo "my environment variable is %VERSION%"
```

You could then use PowerShell to turn it in a pipeline variable:

```
- pwsh: |
    Write-Host "Setting version to: $env:VERSION"
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=version;isOutput=true]$env:VERSION"
  displayName: 'Set version'
  name: set_version
```

After that you can use `$(set_version.version)` in other tasks or parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a secret variable [Microsoft has prepared a manual for that as well](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-secret-variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbash#set-secret-variable-in-a-script-with-logging-commands), in an essence:

```yaml
- bash: |
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=mySecretVal;issecret=true]secretvalue"
- bash: |
    echo $(mySecretVal)
```